# Restart vmware tools

Tags: 14.04, vmware, vmware-tools

Sometimes my Ubuntu virtual machine looses copy/paste from windows host functionality. I'm too lazy restart whole machine. How to restart just vmware tools?

Comment: Start the process after a VMware Tools software upgrade, or if certain features are not working.

Open a terminal window and type the ```vmware-user``` command. Ref [link](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vm_admin.doc/GUID-C6066CB0-33EA-4652-9AB3-0324080DCBEE.html)

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me when the resolution of my Ubuntu 18.10 VM wasn't updating automatically:

`sudo systemctl restart open-vm-tools`

I'm using open-vm-tools/open-vm-tools-desktop 2:10.3.0-0ubuntu3.

Comment: What if we didn't install the VM Tools using command line and we installed it from VMWare's menu? Well I guess in that case, it would be: `vmware-tools.service`

Answer (score 0):

It should generally be fixed by restarting:

```
sudo systemctl restart open-vm-tools
```

but sometimes the work is more complicated and you have to reinstall [ref](https://www.fosslinux.com/68738/install-vmware-tools-on-ubuntu.htm)

```
sudo apt remove open-vm-tools
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt install open-vm-tools
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
sudo reboot
```

Install from host [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Tools).
for more detail see [vmware docs](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Tools/12.3.0/com.vmware.vsphere.vmwaretools.doc/GUID-C48E1F14-240D-4DD1-8D4C-25B6EBE4BB0F.html)